# Is it appropriate to reference scripts that install with your package in the primary module?

Tags: python, module, package, release-management

So I have a library organized like so:

```
\scripts
    myScript.py
\src
    __init__.py
setup.py
```

and in the __init__.py file, suppose I have the line:

```
try:
    from myScript import myFunc
except ImportError:
    RelevantWarning()
    def myFunc(*args, **kwargs):
        RelevantWarning()
```

Where RelevantWarning does whatever to tell the user that foo isn't imported.

When successfully installing the package, this line works just fine.

I have a few questions:

1. Is this a generally acceptable way to reference the script in the library?
2. Is there a best-practice way to do this besides what I'm doing, that isn't just including *myFunc* in the source code? I am not opposed to doing that, I just want to know if there is a standard for referencing these scripts, or a specific reason I shouldn't.
3. In general, is the try-except ImportError a common way to handle optional imports? It seems to be the case, but I want to know explicitly.